# Navlink containing space won't get bold

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use NavLink to bold active link, but some of my link contain space and don't  get bold when clicked, how to fix ?

```
categories.map((c,i) => (
        <NavLink
          key={i}
          exact
          activeClassName="is-active"
          to={`/series/category/${c}`}
        >
          {c}
        </NavLink>
    ))
```

I know for sure that it is due to the spaces because when I do this, links bold correctly (but the redirection doesn't work as my pages must contain space) :

```
to={`/series/category/${c.replace(/\s/g, "")}`}
```

Red squared links won't get bold.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This trick does the job :

```
to={`/series/category/${c.replace(/\s/g, "%20")}`}
```